# Javascript:How to break a while loop when a condition is met to make it so that the loop is terminated when a Var is not null (Break Not Working

Tags: javascript, while-loop, break

```
 var Age;
    
    Age = prompt("How old are you");
    
    while (Age === null){
        prompt("Please Cofirm You Name");
     if (Age > 0 ){
    
        break;
     }
    }
```

I am trying to make it so that the user is in a loop until var Age is not null... My  goal is to make it so that you cant cancel the prompt and have to type in it. I have tried using the break; in an if statement but its not working.
When I use the break; in an if statement it continues to send the prompt
Is there another way to do this
Or is the value of var Age equal to null(even if you add an integer greater then 0) for some reason and if it is anyone know how to fix it
is there are better way to make to user type in the prompt

Thank You in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Age = prompt("How old are you?");
Age = Number(Age);
while (isNaN(Age) || Age < 1) {
    Age = prompt("Please confirm your age.");
    Age = Number(Age);
}
```

In the prompt dialog box, the user can enter anything. So we are trying to see if the user has entered a number by using Number(Age) which tries to parse the user entered value as a number, and returns a number if it is a number.

That means if the user entered value is number, then Age will have a valid number (but it might be negative, which is invalid for our use case). Anything other than a number will give either NaN or 0.

So, when you write `Age = Number(Age)`,

- Age might be assigned with a proper number (positive or negative), or
- NaN (NaN stands for `not a number` and it is considered a type of
  data in JS), or
- 0 when user enters space(s).

In the while loop condition, we are checking whether the user entered value is invalid. That is, `is Age not a number?` or `is Age less than 1?`.

The `||` operator used between these two conditions will return `true` if any one of these two conditions is true (in fact, if the first condition is true, it doesn't even bother to check the second condition, and simply returns true). It returns `false` if both of the conditions are false.

So, if the user has entered invalid input (negative number or space or string), we prompt the user till he enters a proper value.

Comment: I have a question..... What are these 2 lines and what do they do || I know that it is a Logical Operators and means or....but I do not full understand how it can be used and what it truly means in the code you wrote to help me.. If you answer can you please try to use the simplest way of explaining it(Not to many fancy “Coding words”) Thank You in Advance You have been a big help I hope it’s okay to ask for more

Comment: Very Good explanation Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

Try with `do-while`:

```js
let age, age2;

do {
  age = prompt("How old are you?");
} while (age === "");

do {
  age2 = prompt("Please Cofirm Your age");
} while (age2 === "" || age2 !== age);
```

Comment: Thanks but there is one problem that I compleatly forgot to consider...This is if you write nothing in the prompt a press okay it does not loop...But thatyou you have helped alot

Comment: Just use the conditions `(age === ''")`  and `(age2 === ''" ...)`. This is beacuse a prompt has an empty string and not null as return if you have no input.

Answer (score 0):

A while-loop has a break, look at this simple example.

```js
let a = 2;
while (a <100) {
    console.log(a);
    a *= 2;
    if (a===16)
        break;
}
```